# who and w commands in CentOS 8 Docker container

Tags: docker, containers, admin, centos8

While playing with CentOs 8 on Docker container I found out, that outputs of `who` and `w` commands are always empty.

```
[root@9e24376316f1 ~]# who
[root@9e24376316f1 ~]# w
 01:01:50 up  7:38,  0 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.04, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
```

Even when I'm logged in as a different user in second terminal.
When I want to `write` to this user it shows

```
[root@9e24376316f1 ~]# write test
write: test is not logged in
```

Is this because of Docker? Maybe it works in some way that disallow sessions to see each other?
Or maybe that's some other issue. I would really appreciate some explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These utilities obtain the information about current logins from the [utmp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utmp) file (`/var/run/utmp`). You can easily check that in ordinary circumstances (e.g. on the desktop system) this file contains something like the following string (here `qazer` is my login and `tty7` is a TTY where my desktop environment runs):

```
$ cat /var/run/utmp
tty7:0qazer:0�o^�
```

while in the container this file is (*usually*) empty:

```
$ docker run -it centos
[root@5e91e9e1a28e /]# cat /var/run/utmp
[root@5e91e9e1a28e /]#
```

Why?

The `utmp` file is usually modified by programs which authenticate the user and start the session: `login(1)`, `sshd(8)`, `lightdm(1)`. However, the container engine cannot rely on them, as they may be absent in the container file system, so "logging in" and "executing on behalf of" is implemented in the most primitive and straightforward manner, avoiding relying on *anything* inside the container.

When any container is started or any command is `exec`d inside it, the container engine **just** spawns the new process, arranges some security settings, calls `setgid(2)`/`setuid(2)` to forcibly (without any authentication) alter the process' UID/GID and then executes the required binary (the entry point, the command, and so on) within this process.

Say, I start the CentOS container running its main process on behalf of UID `42`:

```
docker run -it --user 42 centos
```

and then try to execute `sleep 1000` inside it:

```
docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID sleep 1000
```

The container engine will perform something like this:

```
[pid 10170] setgid(0)                   = 0
[pid 10170] setuid(42)                  = 0
...
[pid 10170] execve("/usr/bin/sleep", ["sleep", "1000"], 0xc000159740 /* 4 vars */) = 0
```

There will be no writes to `/var/run/utmp`, thus it will remain empty, and `who(1)`/`w(1)` will not find any logins inside the container.

Comment: This is a great answer; if the question gets closed (as it should, being off-topic here), please consider reposting it over at [unix.se] (unless the question is migrated by a moderator, in which case the answer will move with it).